# No page breaks before bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I am writing a thesis, where I am using `book` class.

I use `\include` to include different chapters in my thesis.

Within each chapter, I have a `\bibliography{referenceschapter1}` and so on..The bibliography class that I use is: `unsrt` and I am using BibTex.

Everything goes well, but the bibliography starts on a new page within each chapter.

But, I want to start the bibliography immediately at the end of the chapter, so "Without clearing the page". I tried `\let\clearpage\relax`, but it seems not to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you want the `\bibliography` to default to `\section*` rather than `\chapter*`?

Comment: @Werner  yes, exactly..I now tried changing it in the book class, from chapter*  to section* (the bibliography)   but that did not solve the problem

Comment: You could try `{\let\chapter\section\bibliography{<file>}}` (note the use of `{..}`), but we would need more information to address the problem if this doesn't work.

Comment: @Werner  Sorry about that. The code indeed works very well and fixes the problem. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Typically a `\bibliography` in a class that provides chapters are set as a chapter. Since you're using `book`, this seems to be the case. A local redefinition to use `\section` instead of `\chapter` might be a feasible option.

In your preamble, add

```
\let\oldbibliography\bibliography% Store \bibliography in \oldbibliography
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{{%
  \let\chapter\section% Copy \section over \chapter
  \oldbibliography{#1}}}% Old \bibliography
```

which provides a local redefinition of `\chapter` to `\section` whenever you call `\bibliography`.

[`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) provides an easier interface to change this, if you ever need it.

Comment: I noticed that in line with this problem: After doing this, although my references start as a section, but the header that I have are still called References, instead of the name of the chapter. In the Preamble, I define them as \fancyhead[LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}; How can I change the header of pages with references to not as references, but the chaptertitle.

Comment: @abhishek: What document class are you using?

Comment: I am using Book class

Comment: @abhishek: It seems unusual that `\section` would influence `\leftmark`. Perhaps you could use `\let\oldbibliography\bibliography \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{{%
  \let\chapter\section \let\sectionmark\@gobble
  \oldbibliography{#1}}} \makeatother` I've just added `\let\sectionmark\@gobble` which should remove any mark inserted by `\section`. If you're using other titling packages this may not work; regardless, it's ideal if you could supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), even if it's just temporarily on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.org).

Comment: And I should paste the code in preamble?

Comment: @abhishek: You should post something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see your exact problem. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I now pasted my preamble and main document at http://pastebin.com/Fsjqy6v3

Comment: @abhishek: I can't replicate the problem with the code you provided. I added some `\lipsum` text, together with a fake `\section{references}` as part of `\chapter{introduction}` (_not_ `\include{introduction}`) and the headings didn't change. Consider viewing the problem from my end: I don't know your setup, so the best way let me understand it, is to spoon-feed me the information. Have you read through the post showing how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? Please do so, then revisit posting the code. As mentioned before: copy-and-paste-and-compile is ideal.